# Hide Feedback Box Modern Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, iframe, modern-experience, modern-pages

I have an iframe in my classic sp page referencing some webparts of a modern page. However the modern page is pulling back the feedback box.

I have looked at the modern page and css cant be over ridden. How can this be hidden?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give the iframe element a “id”, for example:

```
<iframe id="iframeID" src="<path>"></iframe>
```

Use F12 to check the Feedback element

[image]

Then use the following script to hide it:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var f=$('#iframeID')
        f.load(function(){ 
            f.contents().find('.feedback_88fc6c94').hide(); 
        })
    })
</script>
```

Save the page and refresh, the Feedback will disappear.

Comment: Sorry just a question does the iframeID have to be the div class? and also what does the path relate to?